# emoticons replace array with "<3"

Tags: php, arrays, emoticons

I wanted to put some nice looking smileys in my chat on my site, but unfortunately the "<3" array to put a heart smiley in my chat doesn't work for some reason, all the other ones work fine, I think the "<" is causing this problem. But I don't know how to fix this, take a look in the code below:

```
$patterns = array(':)', ':D', ':p', ':P', ':(', '(aapje)', '8)', '<3');
$replacements = array('<img src="smiles/smile.gif"/>', '<img src="smiles/bigsmile.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/tongue.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/tongue.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/sad.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/aapje.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/nerd.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/love.png"/>');

$message = str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $message);
```

code update

```
$patterns = array(':)', ':D', ':p', ':P', ':(', '(aapje)', '8)', '/</3', '(l)');
         $replacements = array('<img src="smiles/smile.gif"/>', '<img src="smiles/bigsmile.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/tongue.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/tongue.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/sad.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/aapje.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/nerd.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/love.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/love.png"/>');
         $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
         $blankexp = "/^\n/";
         $message = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['message']), ENT_QUOTES);

         if (!preg_match($blankexp, $message)) {

             if (preg_match($reg_exUrl, $message, $url)) {
                $message = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" target="_blank">'.$url[0].'</a>', $message);
             } 
             $message = str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $message);
```

Thx and Grts.

Comment: did you use strip_tags or something like this?

Comment: yes i did look at the update :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be due to `<` sign. Try html entity for `<`- use `&lt;`

Following code should work:

```
$message = htmlspecialchars("Love Smiley <3");
$patterns = array(':)', ':D', ':p', ':P', ':(', '(aapje)', '8)', '&lt;3');
$replacements = array('<img src="smiles/smile.gif"/>', '<img src="smiles/bigsmile.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/tongue.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/tongue.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/sad.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/aapje.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/nerd.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/love.png"/>');

$message = str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $message);

echo $message;
```

Comment: @Shumail92 i think the function is already htmlspecialchars safe

Comment: Thx man it's working, I used the strip_tags thing :p thanks everybody who tried to figger this out.

Comment: Welcome. Vote UP for me as well by clikcing the UP Arrow on left side of my answer.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: Yeah i edited my answer. So undo it please

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `<` to `&lt;` - I'd imagine your code is trying to parse anything after it as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&lt;` instead of `<`:

```
$message = htmlspecialchars("I love you!!! <3 <3 <3"); // defining message

$patterns = array(':)', ':D', ':p', ':P', ':(', '(aapje)', '8)', '&lt;3');
$replacements = array('<img src="smiles/smile.gif"/>', '<img src="smiles/bigsmile.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/tongue.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/tongue.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/sad.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/aapje.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/nerd.png"/>', '<img src="smiles/love.png"/>');    
$message = str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $message);

echo $message;
```